# Classify text using NaiveBayesClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I have a text file with a sentence on each line:
eg ""Have you registered your email ID with your Bank Account?"

I want to classify it into interrogative or not. FYI these are sentences from bank websites.
I've seen [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26427/how-to-extract-question-s-from-document-with-nltk)
with this nltk code block:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('nps_chat')
posts = nltk.corpus.nps_chat.xml_posts()[:10000]


def dialogue_act_features(post):
    features = {}
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(post):
        features['contains({})'.format(word.lower())] = True
    return features

featuresets = [(dialogue_act_features(post.text), post.get('class')) for post in posts]
size = int(len(featuresets) * 0.1)
train_set, test_set = featuresets[size:], featuresets[:size]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))
```

So I did some preprocessing to my text file i.e. stemming words, removing stop words etc, to make each sentence into a bag of words. From the code above, I have a trained classifier. How do I implement it on my text file of sentences (either raw or preprocessed)?

Update: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q-bcyoDHckGgK7aRy-tiLUtfPPfBDpZB/view?usp=sharing) is an example of my text file.

Comment: You need to convert the documents using (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) and then use the classifier. Can you upload your data?

Comment: @seralouk thank you for your response, I will look at the link now! I have updated the question with an example of my data.

Comment: not sure why I'm being downvoted, is there any more information I should be providing?

Comment: @seralouk no they are all strings of sentences. I have given the preprocessed version. If you want I can attach the processed version where numbers are taken out, words are stemmed, and stopwords are removed?

Comment: @seralouk can't I train the classifier using nps_chat and get the sample data from that?

Comment: no it's okay. I am going to post an answer now. So you have two classes, interogative and not interogative right?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. If possible, interrogative/affirmative would be brilliant.

Comment: okay and the preprocessed sentences are like this `x= np.array([[-3,7],[1,5]])` ?

Comment: no, no, that was just a snippet of code I found. An example is "Have you registered your email ID with your Bank Account?"

Comment: sorry if I'm being confusing, the second code  snippet was something I just found as an example and I was wondering if I could use it for text by training it on the nltk corpus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171978/discussion-between-seralouk-and-polkadot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assuming that you have preprocessed the document data as we discussed, you can do the following:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('nps_chat')
posts = nltk.corpus.nps_chat.xml_posts()[:10000]


def dialogue_act_features(post):
    features = {}
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(post):
        features['contains({})'.format(word.lower())] = True
    return features

featuresets = [(dialogue_act_features(post.text), post.get('class')) for post in posts]
size = int(len(featuresets) * 0.1)
train_set, test_set = featuresets[size:], featuresets[:size]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(featuresets)
print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))

0.668
```

---

### For your data, you can iterate in your lines and fit, predict:

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(featuresets)
print(classifier.classify(dialogue_act_features(line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this for all lines in the text file works:

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(featuresets)
print(classifier.classify(dialogue_act_features(line)))
```